# Powershell wildcards usage for writing powershell scripts

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, wildcard

What does the following expression in a .ps1(powershell script) file mean?

```
$row=".+\\(.+\.exe)";
```

From what I understand, "\" is used to escape and makes the proceeding character be taken literally. But I am confused by the usage of "." here. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like this is part of a regular expression that matches file paths. Breaking this regular expression down:

```
.+        matches one or more characters (of anything)
\\        matches the '\' character (needs the \ to escape the \ character)
(    
   .+     matches one or more characters (of anything)
   \.     matches the '.' character (needs the \ to escape the . character)
   exe    matches exe
)
```

The . is a special character that means match any character.

Comment: But what then is the difference between .+ and .*?

Comment: .+ means match 1 or more character, and .* means match 0 or more characters.

Comment: So just to provide an example .+ and .* would match "a". However, .+ will not match "" whereas .* would.

Comment: Just to clarify: ".+" or ".*" does not mean a "." and then the number of characters right? It is just number of characters without the ".". For eg.: if I have ".\\", it is just "\"? I am confused because I am looking at a match for ".\\abc". So it can be ".\abc or just the end of the path \abc".

Comment: The + and the * are what's known as a Quantification. They modify how much the preceding element should appear (which in this case is a . which is a metacharacter that means match any character). The key difference between + and * is the minimum number of times the character needs to appear. In the example that you have above, it just means match one or more characters before the \abc.exe

Comment: So if I want to check for executions, I should use something like "\.\\abc"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by exectuions, but "\.\\abc" would match ".\abc" only.

Comment: Jus a follow up on this one. If I have $a="The month is feb(ruary)" and $b="february", I get $a -match $b is true, but if I use $a="a: b  explorer, executing abc.exe" and $b=".+\\(.+\.exe)", I get $a -match $b is false.... Why is that?